# incorrect values when multiplying columns in mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using dplyr in R, and it seems that I am getting incorrect values when multiplying two columns of my tibble (new column created in mutate() called "multiply"). However, dividing the columns does seem to produce the correct values (column called "divide"). Here is the R code and tibble.

[image]

[image]

Im using dplyr version 1.0.10

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Computationally there is no issue here; you seem to have an issue relating to the degree of precision reported to you when viewing a tibble. Whereas in base R this might be addressed via the scipen option; for tibbles you can change the number of significant figures to show via

```
options(pillar.sigfig=5)
```

to raise them to 5 for example.

```
options(pillar.sigfig=3)
tibble::tibble(x=35*7.14)
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# x
# <dbl>
#   1  250.
# 
options(pillar.sigfig=5)
tibble::tibble(x=35*7.14)
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# x
# <dbl>
# 1 249.9

options(pillar.sigfig=3)
tibble::tibble(x=37 * 6.76)
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# x
# <dbl>
#   1  250.
# 
options(pillar.sigfig=5)
tibble::tibble(x=37 * 6.76)
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# x
# <dbl>
# 1 250.12
```

p.s. notice that in both cases where 3 sigfigs were used tibble printed a trailing `.` this is a sign that you aren't getting full precision on the display

more examples :

```
xt <-tibble(x=43*5.813953488)
options(pillar.sigfig=5)
xt
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# x
# <dbl>
#   1 250.00

options(pillar.sigfig=10)
# xt
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# x
# <dbl>
#   1 250.0000000

options(pillar.sigfig=50)
xt |> mutate(xc = as.character(x))
## A tibble: 1 × 2
#              x xc           
#          <dbl> <chr>        
#1 249.999999984 249.999999984
```

I wont be looking at any more screenshots you provide; if you wish me to consider your data/results; then please provide them in a text based format; i.e. dput()

Comment: Thankyou @Nir Graham, but running that option does not help. Please see, for example the last row on the tibble. Why is it showing that 35 * 7.14 equals 250 in the multiply column? And the row above this: 37 * 6.76 is also showing as 250! These are not correct!

Comment: 35 * 7.14 = 249.9 ; or 250 to 3 significant figures; setting to 5 sig figs; gives 249.9; everything is fine.

Comment: Still not working Im afraid (please see updated image). I tried setting to 10 significant figures but those bunch of 250's are still there!

Comment: I guess the problem is that by changing the precision on all columns, the "multiply" column still looks the same in the end? Is it that the answer has so many zeros after the decimal point that it just displays as an integer?